Hello, I can't seem to identify the problem of why my ECG value(AD8232) is negative and not giving me a proper reading. What do I need to change
import machine
import time
from blynklib import Blynk

# Initialize Blynk with your auth token
BLYNK_AUTH = 'fgVF4IWzS-RFyKmb8DvNTKfm8Rwgt0JU'
blynk = Blynk(BLYNK_AUTH)

adcpin = 4
sensor = machine.ADC(adcpin)

LO_POS_PIN = 15
LO_NEG_PIN = 14
adc = machine.ADC(1)  # Initialize ADC on pin GP27_AD

# Configure pins
lo_pos_pin = machine.Pin(LO_POS_PIN, machine.Pin.IN)
lo_neg_pin = machine.Pin(LO_NEG_PIN, machine.Pin.IN)

# Function to read temperature
def ReadTemperature():
    adc_value = sensor.read_u16()
    volt = (3.3/65535) * adc_value
    temperature = 27 - (volt - 0.706)/0.001721
    return round(temperature, 1)

# Function to read ECG signal
def read_ecg():
    ecg_signal = lo_pos_pin.value() - lo_neg_pin.value()
    return ecg_signal

# Function to convert ECG signal to voltage
def convert_to_voltage(ecg_signal):
    # Assuming 3.3V reference voltage
    voltage = (ecg_signal / 1023) * 3.3
    return voltage

# Main loop
while True:
    # Reading temperature
    temperature = ReadTemperature()
    print("Temperature:", temperature)
    blynk.virtual_write(1, temperature)  # Send temperature data to virtual pin V1

    # Reading ECG signal
    ecg_value = read_ecg()
    voltage = convert_to_voltage(ecg_value)
    adc_value = adc.read_u16()

    print("ECG Value:", ecg_value)
    print("Voltage:", voltage)
    print("ADC Value:", adc_value)

    blynk.virtual_write(2, ecg_value)  # Send ECG value to virtual pin V2
    blynk.virtual_write(3, voltage)  # Send voltage value to virtual pin V3
    blynk.virtual_write(4, adc_value)  # Send ADC value to virtual pin V4

    blynk.run()

    time.sleep(1)

The pin connections for Ad8232
Lo+ - pin 15
Lo- - pin 14
Vout - pin 27
Vin - 3V3
Gnd - gnd


ECG signals are often susceptible to noise interference.You may need to add filtering techniques such as averaging or digital filtering to reduce noise in the signal.

In case you need to know more about  ECG signals, you can see here: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2017/08/introduction-to-ecg.html It will give you an elaboration on Introduction to ECG signal and its properties.
